# Форма обратной связи

Tags: javascript, html, php, mysql

как будет форма обратной связи(отправка e-mail) так, чтобы почта не задействовалась, просто от сервера письмо на твой e-mail шло, как на leonbets(запроса mailto нет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mail("seosprint0@yandex.ru", "Тема сообщения", "Текст сообщения\nСтрока2\nСтрока3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вы сами пишете, что отсылать письмо надо именно от сервера. Какой язык является Веб серверным? PHP, конечно же ! Чтобы отослать на нем почту, надо воспользоваться простенькой функцией **"mail()"**, которая отсылает сообщение на нужный почтовый ящик.

Вот только эта функция не должна быть запрещена хотером =)

Comment: можете расписать подробнее как функция применяется, допустим текст :
Привет, скажи свое имя
А e-mail seosprint0@yandex.ru

Comment: Я-то написать могу, но вы хоть  как-то знакомы с PHP ?

Comment: mail("mail@mail.ru", "Тема", "Текст сообщения".$handlers);